# CAML Query get elements with most recent created date

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I'm trying to get the elements with the most new created date using CAML query in sharepoint 2007.

I can do it using:

```
"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>"
```

To get the most recent date and then use other CAML query to get the elements with that date.

But, theres no other way to do it in one consult?

Comment: What's your issue? You just add a ViewFields node to get the fields you want.

Comment: I think Daniel is asking if he has to do two queries, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a specific date (eg : all the news that were created five years ago, but you don't know the magic number five) I would do the same, you can always limit the viewfields in your query to limit the fields that are retrieved (already well stripped with rowlimit=1).

There might be a way with groupby to get something similar or you can get the last x items order by date (if you know that for example, no more than x items are created per specific date) and do some post processing in Linq, but at first sight, you're on the good track.